# Microsoft Office365 Get User OAuth Authorizations

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to write get the OAuth Authorizations in Office365 for my enterprise.
Is there any way to view and manipulate them besides: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/oauth2permissiongrant_get
The API is in beta and the /users endpoint of it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell:

[Get-​Azure​AD​OAuth2​Permission​Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadoauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0)

[Get-​Azure​AD​Service​Principal​OAuth2​Permission​Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipaloauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0)

[Get-​Azure​AD​User​OAuth2​Permission​Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduseroauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0)